# How to get (h1 + (span)) + (h2) into (span) + (h1) + (h2) ...?

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the cryptic title of this post, but ... on [this responsive webpage](http://www.centrummeeuwenveen.nl/txp/) the HTML of the header is:

```
<!-- header -->
<header>
<hgroup>
<!-- space (&nbsp;) in <span> is necessary to show background-image (logo)! -->
<h1><txp:site_name /><span>&nbsp;</span></h1>
<h2><txp:site_slogan /></h2>
</hgroup>
</header>
```

With `text-align:center;` on `header` (and some other CSS) I get what I want ... on wide media that is. On small devices it becomes very messy (off course).

My question: is it possible with above HTML to stack (center) everything in this order:

```
| logo |
|  h1  |
|  h2  |
```

... so that it can fit nicely on smaller screens?

Comment: Look into flexbox model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the flexbox model

something like:

```
    display: flex;        /* Lay out each item using flex layout */
    flex-flow: column;    /* Lay out item's contents vertically  */
```

[This generator may help](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/)

Comment: I've never used flexbox. With the generator it's quiet easy.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using `float` property, `text-align` and `clear` getting little help from pseudo-element `:before`

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/rfElA `<h1>` text is wrap in a container too , here  a `<b>` for the purpose of the show. it is the only way to clear down the text.

`<span>`, should be an  `<img>` for the logo with a nice `alt="trademark logo"` , so it exists :) .

Comment: If this CSS is fine with you, use media queries to set it where/when needed :) , for the layout, display:flex would surely be a good one too.

Comment: well you are using flexbox , it works with FireFox , but not with chrome. I guess a matter of prefix. maybe you know this already ? http://flexiejs.com/playground/ or this one http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Comment: Sorry ... I was fiddling with flexbox. Now I'm back with your floating solution. In your codepen it's working ... not on [my page](http://goo.gl/d7vVi). Will you have a look at the HTML and [CSS](http://goo.gl/l3pKn) please. Thanks!